# How to send alerts in APIC Test and Monitor?

Tags: apiconnect-test-monitor

On the introduction page for the 'APIC Test and Monitor tool' one of the listed features is 'Get alerts on your API Health'. However once inside the tool I can't find any reference on how to generate alerts...
Is it already possibble? Or just an idea for the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question, thank you for asking. You are absolutely right, we are working on shipping notification/alerts as a *pluggable ecosystem*. We are building a fully featured API and Webhooks, any platform that leverages an API can be used, as well as email and SMS.

Out of the box we will provide the most popular plugins such as the following:

- Slack
- BigPanda
- HipChat
- StatusPage.io
- JIRA
- Twilio
- DataDog
- New Relic
- Elastic

You will also be able to create alert groups, ex. specific tests/monitoring can be mapped to specific groups.

Will update this space when it becomes available. Your feedback is helpful, what is your preferred method to be notified by?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For now, since I'm just playing around with it, my preferred method is e-mail. However being able to make an API call would be a great feature

Comment: Tim, email alerts are going live imminently.